# array within class module

Tags: excel, vba

i'm trying to create a class module that contains an array, and i would like to fill this array automaticaly. But something weird happens when i try to access and fill the array:

This is my class module

```
Private my_arr() As Double

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim my_arr(1 To 16, 1 To 16)
End Sub

Public Property Let arr(i As Long, j As Long, MyValue As Double)
    my_arr(i, j) = MyValue
End Property
```

And this is my main module than instanciate the class module

```
Sub main()
Dim instance As Object
Dim i, j As Long
Set instance = New Test

instance.arr(1, 1) = 1 'Works
i = 1
j = 1

instance.arr(i, j) = 1 'Doesn't work

instance.arr(i + 0, j + 0) = 1 'Works
End Sub
```

I don't understand why i can't acces my array using variables..

Do you guys have an idea please ?

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: `i` is declared `As Variant`. You cannot pass it `ByRef As Long`.

Comment: You have to dim each variable: `Dim i as long, j As Long`